# How to create interactive panels with changing textures and colors in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, 2d-games

I'm new here but I did some research before posting. My goal is to create a simple tower defense game using a couple of interesting ideas and moreover to train my development skills using javax.swing and java.awt. As far as I know, developers are mostly lazy guys and they do everything to make their life more simple.

There is map with a grid and for map loading my game uses a boolean matrix and a loading method to locate terrain on panels. I thought it will be quite simple solution. Because the matrix is 12 x 12, I would like to create it with some other application rather than entering a line of 144 numbers.

Here comes an idea to first create a map editor application and later do maps for levels in it. When I have such a tool I could make that map visually and then save its boolean matrix to a file, which later can be read by loading method and recreated in game. Next step is to make graphics and also panels that would react properly on user's actions. On the left there is a panel with buttons - after user clicks one of them, the field currentColor changes.

This field is used by method that implements actionListener and makes color change of the panel that is declared in its constructor. I wanted to change color of certain panel when its clicked. I use colors because its easier for now to make it working, later I want to replace color with a texture - obviously, I know I have to use a paintComponent method, but I assume that will work for it too, right? Also would be nice if the panel border changes color when I move my cursor over it and changes it back to normal when mouse is somewhere else.

The point here is that I'm having some trouble to make panels interactive. First problem is that panels are created in for loop and that makes it difficult to refer to a certain panel while mouse is over it. Another one comes with that I would like to change appearance of that panel after I click on it.

As far as I know, MouseListeners should do the work, but how to actually write it to have an effect on screen? I found some post about that, but for me it doesn't work. Here's the link: [highlighting panels in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769190/how-can-i-highlight-jpanels-on-mouse-hover)

My code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Editor extends JFrame
{
    private JButton towers = new JButton(new ImageIcon("pu.gif"));
    private JButton road = new JButton(new ImageIcon("pu.gif"));
    private JButton start = new JButton(new ImageIcon("pu.gif"));
    private JButton finish = new JButton(new ImageIcon("pu.gif"));
    private String mapTitle = "testmap";
    private Color currentColor;
    private int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    private int height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    private String currentMapType = "Standard";
    private static final int currentHeight = 12;
    private static final int currentWidth = 12;
    private JPanel[][] currentMapPanel;
    private int[][] currentMapField;

    //Toolbar - a panel with buttons

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,3));

    //Container for map - a panel with map

    private Dimension containerSize = new Dimension(height, height);
    static JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(currentHeight, currentWidth), true);

    //Separator

    private JSplitPane separator = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panel, container);

    public Editor()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents()
    {
        this.setTitle(mapTitle + ".map" + " - " + "Game Map Editor");
        this.setSize(800, 600);

        int frameWidth = this.getSize().width;
        int frameHeight = this.getSize().height;
        this.setLocation((width - frameWidth) / 2, (height - frameHeight) / 2);

        this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("pu.gif"));

        towers.addActionListener(e -> {
            currentColor = Color.CYAN;
            System.out.println(currentColor);
        });
        road.addActionListener(e -> {
            currentColor = Color.GRAY;
            System.out.println(currentColor);
        });
        start.addActionListener(e -> {
            currentColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
            System.out.println(currentColor);
        });
        finish.addActionListener(e -> {
            currentColor = Color.BLACK;
            System.out.println(currentColor);
        });

        new Map(currentMapType, currentWidth, currentHeight, false);

        panel.add(towers);
        panel.add(road);
        panel.add(start);
        panel.add(finish);

        this.getContentPane().add(separator);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    /**
     * Class that allows to load the graphic map and to view it in JFrame
     */
    public class Map
    {
        public Map(String mapType, int rows, int columns, boolean load)
        {
            if (!load)
            {
                currentMapPanel = mapPanel(rows, columns);
                currentMapField = new MapGenerator().mapFieldEmpty(rows, columns);
                mapLoader(currentMapField, currentMapPanel);
            }
            else
            {
                currentMapPanel = mapPanel(rows, columns);
                currentMapField = new MapGenerator().mapFieldGenerator(rows, columns);
                mapLoader(currentMapField, currentMapPanel);
            }
        }

        private JPanel[][] mapPanel(int rows, int columns)
        {
            JPanel[][] mapPanel = new JPanel[rows][columns];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns - 1; j++)
                {
                    mapPanel[i][j] = new JPanel(true);
                    mapPanel[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height/12, height/12));
                    mapPanel[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                    mapPanel[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                            super.mouseEntered(e);
                            JPanel parent = (JPanel) e.getSource();
                            new colorListener(parent, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                            parent.revalidate();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
                        {
                            super.mouseExited(e);
                            JPanel parent = (JPanel) e.getSource();
                            new colorListener(parent, Color.GREEN);
                            parent.revalidate();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                        {
                            super.mouseClicked(e);
                            JPanel parent = (JPanel) e.getSource();
                            new colorListener(parent, currentColor);
                            parent.revalidate();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return mapPanel;
        }

        private void mapLoader(int[][] mapField, JPanel[][] mapPanel)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mapField.length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mapField.length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (mapField[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        mapPanel[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        container.add(mapPanel[i][j]);
                    }
                    else if (mapField[i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        mapPanel[i][j].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                        container.add(mapPanel[i][j]);
                    }
                    else if (mapField[i][j] == 2)
                    {
                        mapPanel[i][j].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                        container.add(mapPanel[i][j]);
                    }
                    else if (mapField[i][j] == 3)
                    {
                        mapPanel[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        container.add(mapPanel[i][j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("An error occurred...");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private JPanel mapContainer(int rows, int columns)
        {
            container = new JPanel();
            container.setLayout(createLayout(rows, columns));
            container.setPreferredSize(containerSize);
            container.setBounds(height/4, height/4, containerSize.width, containerSize.height);
            return container;
        }
        private GridLayout createLayout(int rows, int columns){
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(rows, columns);
            return layout;
        }
    }

    private class colorListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public colorListener(JPanel p, Color c)
        {
            this.panel = p;
            this.color = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(color);
        }

        JPanel panel;
        Color color;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Editor().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for a component to be interactive, it must first be added to a container which is realised (attaches to a native peer). Based on what I can see, none of your map panels are been added to any container which is been displayed on the screen. One concept you should take the time to learn is the “model-view-controller”, where the state is “modelled”, this is then used by the controller/view to display it in an independent manner

Comment: Don’t call super.mouseEntered(e); (or the others) this is not required and will likely cause you no end of issues, as these methods delegate to the MouseListeners

Answer (score 1):

The question is broad and the answer complicated.

Essentially, you want to do some research into concepts such as "separation of responsibilities" and "decoupling code".

The idea is that you break down you functionality requirements so that your objects are doing a single, specialised job.  You also "decouple" the code so that changing the implementation of one part won't adversely affect other parts of the program.  This is commonly achieved through the use of interfaces.

You will also want to investigate the concept of "model-view-controller", where by the "data" or "state" is modelled in one or more classes, but is wholly independent of the UI.  The UI is then free to "render" the model in what ever way it feels is appropriate.

In this way, the "view" (interacting with the controller) can change the state (or react to the change in state) of the model, making it easier to mange (no seriously, it does)

## Code Review ...

This...

```
static JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(currentHeight, currentWidth), true);
```

is dangerous and a bad idea.  It voids the concept of encapsulation and allows any one to create new instance of `container` at any time, without notification, which will disconnect it from what the program was previously using.  In fact, you actually do this.

`static` is not your friend.  Used correctly, it's useful, but used in this way, it's just a bad idea and should be avoid.

You should instead favour "dependency injection", where the "elements" that any one object relies on are passed to it.

I would avoid things like...

```
this.setSize(800, 600);

int frameWidth = this.getSize().width;
int frameHeight = this.getSize().height;
this.setLocation((width - frameWidth) / 2, (height - frameHeight) / 2);
```

Windows are complicated components, which also contain window decorations which wrap about the content.  This means that the available space to the content is `window size - window decorations`.  Instead.  You should rely on the layout manager API to provide appropriate sizing hints and `pack` the frame.

On most modern OSs you have "other" system elements, which, again, reduces the amount of available space on the screen (docks, task bars, other funky stuff).  Instead, you can use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to centre the window more reliably on the screen.

Instead of `setIconImage`, you should be using [`Window#setIconImages(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages(java.util.List)), which allows you to pass a number of images which can be used by the API to represent the application in different places that require different resolution images.

Not sure what ...

```
new Map(currentMapType, currentWidth, currentHeight, false);
```

but it's not really helping.

If you find yourself just creating an instance of class without actually maintaining a reference to it, then it's probably a good sign of a bad design.

Your `Map` class raises a bunch of questions which aren't easily answered.  It kind of makes me worried that the `Map` class is modifying the state of the parent class and screams "dependency injection" instead.

This...

```
mapPanel[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height / 12, height / 12));
```

is best avoided.  You should prefer overriding `getPreferredSize` and it should simply return a "desired" size, which could then be used by things like `GridLayout` to layout the component more effectively.

This then leads into the "separation of responsibility".  This section suggestions you should have a "tile" class, which would be self managed and responsible for a single element from the model.

There are a number of things wrong with your mouse event handling...

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mouseEntered(e);
    JPanel parent = (JPanel) e.getSource();
    new colorListener(parent, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    parent.revalidate();
}
```

You shouldn't be calling `super.mouseXxx(e)` on of the jobs of those methods is to call the delegate `MouseListener`s, so, mess right there.

You can more easily use `e.getComponent()` to get a reference to the component which generated the event, but if panel was a self contained unit of work (ie `Tile`) and the `MouseListener` an anonymous or inner class, you'd be able to forego the cast altogether.

`new colorListener(parent, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);` scares me as it's setting up a bunch of strongly references objects which can't be easily dereferenced, nor am I clear on there intent.

`parent.revalidate();` isn't doing what you seem to think it's doing.

`revalidate` generates a new layout pass, what you seem to want is `repaint`.

These...

```
container.setPreferredSize(containerSize);
container.setBounds(height / 4, height / 4, containerSize.width, containerSize.height);
```

are just bad ideas.  Let the content of the container, along with the layout manager deal with.

So, the short answer is, you have a lot of research left to do, things like:

- OO design patterns
- OO good practices, including "separation of responsibilities", "code decoupling" and in a more general sense, "dependency injection"
- Model-View-Controller, coding to interface instead of implementation

just to name a few

Comment: There's a lot of useful information here and I'm still doing research, but I wanted to ask some questions. I think I understand the conception of MVC pattern now. But let's say I would like to go step further and create a history of states (of course I want only to save state change of map objects, not entire application).
How do I do this? Do I have to create another list or mix patterns like memento with MVC or use serialization or what? If it's possible to reference a component that was clicked I could use a method to create JButtons, JPanels etc. and then create them all in a loop, right?

Comment: Undo is basically a FILO stack

Comment: Ok, so does that mean I create a stack and because it's LIFO I need to sort out all its elements in opposite order to make it FILO? That's a bit confusing because in the end both FILO and LIFO have just different in out order, but everything else seems to be the same. Also I noticed that in a lot of applications you can't undo all the operations sometimes. Does that mean they have certain amount of saved states because the stack has its capacity and the first element is removed when the capacity is reached?

Comment: There are lifo stack implementations in the jdk (from memory), but it’s not hard to mimic. What and how much you can undo is application specific and comes down to any number of factors